# Table inside another table

Tags: css, html-table

I had table inside the another table, my inner table display the image, if I enter the text after the inner table, the text should display right side of the table and the bottom of the  inner table. How do I do this?

"the below code display the outer table text always displayed below the inner table"

### Heading

```
<table class="">
    <tr style=" width:500px; float:left;">
        <td style="border: thin ridge #008000; text-align:left;" align="left"; >
            <table class="" 
                style=" border: 1px solid #800000; width:200px; float:left; height: 200px;">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
                        stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow&nbsp; </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            stackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
            stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
            stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
            stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
            stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow 
            stackoverflowstackoverflow stackoverflowstackoverflow statackoverflow sta</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add `float: left;` to the table via CSS. This will accomplish what you are looking for as it will pull the table out of the normal flow of elements and the text should wrap around to the right and bottom like you described.